# Ubuntu won't boot with Windows 10 hard drive connected

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu (not my first time); however, it does not boot up with my *Windows 10* hard drive connected. I enter BIOS, select my hard drive with Ubuntu, but the computer boots into Windows 10.  The only time Ubuntu boots is when I physically remove the Windows 10 hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your UBUNTU HDD connected as slave. And Windows HDD - as master(You can check it out in BIOS). Try to switch them

Comment: I entered my bios but I could not find the option to switch from slave to master.

Comment: Slave and Master is controlled by either the location on the IDE cable or via jumper on the disk drive.